# How to get first displayed document line number if line wrapping is enabled?

Tags: c++, scintilla

I use `SCI_GETFIRSTVISIBLELINE` of Scintilla in order to get the first displayed line of the document.

Now, I enabled word wrapping mode by setting `SCI_SETWRAPMODE` to `SC_WRAP_WORD`. But `SCI_GETFIRSTVISIBLELINE` does not match the document line any more.

Is there a way to get the first displayed document line (also, how to know if the displayed line is part of a wrapped line)? Scintilla itself knows it, as the correct line number is displayed before the text (when enabling `SC_MARGIN_NUMBER`).

*Update*: The first document line of the visible line can be get by calling `SCI_DOCLINEFROMVISIBLE` with the result of `SCI_GETFIRSTVISIBLELINE`. However, detecting partial lines is still a problem.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The corresponding document line of first visible line can be get by calling `SCI_DOCLINEFROMVISIBLE` with the result of `SCI_GETFIRSTVISIBLELINE`: `DOCLINEFROMVISIBLE(GETFIRSTVISIBLELINE())`

The second part is a bit more tricky and seems a bit hacky to me:

First, I call `SCI_WRAPCOUNT` with the document line number of the first line and get the number of rows this line uses. If `SCI_WRAPCOUNT()>1` it's a candidate for a partial line. The number of skipped lines can be calculated with `SCI_DOCLINEFROMVISIBLE(SCI_GETFIRSTVISIBLELINE() + SCI_WRAPCOUNT() - 1) - SCI_DOCLINEFROMVISIBLE(SCI_GETFIRSTVISIBLELINE())`.